# How to set the App Icon in Flash CS6?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, adobe

I have an AIR application ready for deployment, but I can't figure out how to set the icon in the flash builder. I have a nice looking 512x512 icon that I want to use, but when I click publish, it only allows for up to 72x72??

Please explain? Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

But why? There is no 512x512 for Android platform. Please read about [available icon sizes](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WS901d38e593cd1bac1e63e3d129907d2886-8000.html) for various platforms and how to use them.

> On Android, the icons specified in the application descriptor are used as the application Launcher icon. The application Launcher icon should be supplied as a set of 36x36-, 48x48-, 72x72-, 96x96-, and 144x144- pixel PNG images. These icon sizes are used for low-density, medium-density, and high-density screens, respectively.

Comment: Yes, but how do I set it? I don't even see the option for 96x96 or 144x144